# createXMLStreamReader giving cannot evaluate com.ctc.wstx.io.BranchingReadingSource.toString

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot, gradle

I am using jdk8/spring boot2/gradle 7. Trying to unmarshall but getting below error:

> reader property msInput gives method threw
> "java.lang.NullPointerException" exception..cannot evaluate
> com.ctc.wstx.io.BranchingReaderSource.toString().

code fragement:

```
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = JAXBContext.newInstance(Response.class, ErrorResponse.class).createUnmarshaller();
String subStr = archResponse.gethildText("Document").trim();
XMLStreamReader reader = xif.createXMLStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(subStr));
unmarshaller.unmarshal(reader);
```

lib used:

- woodstox-core:6.4.0
- stax2-api:4.2.1

Please help.

changing library versions.

Comment: Unfortunately your question is very obscure. You can make it easier for people to help, by copying the exact code (your hand-written sample has typos which make it more confusing) and by pasting the stack trace and pointing out which line in your code sample the stack trace refers to.